# Email html link to visualforce page embedded within lightning standard side and top bars

Tags: visualforce, email, lightning

I'm generating a custom html email that is sent using the `Messaging.sendEmail` method.
In it I have a link to a custom visualforce page.  Say for example the link is this:
https://yyyy.na99.visual.force.com/apex/mypage?id=0011100002a3b4ABBC

If the user that clicks the link is in classic mode then all is grand.  It displays the page with the normal classic side and top bars.
If the user is in lightning mode however it goes to the page sans the lightning sidebar. Worse, when I click on an opportunity link on the page, it goes through the lightning logo load screen.

Is there a more formal url approach that the Salesforce system would handle the link correctly? I.e. go to classic if the user is in classic mode and go to visualforce page embedded within Salesforce side and header bars?